# Perl IO::Socket::UNIX Connect with Timeout gives EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK

Tags: perl, sockets, nonblocking, unix-socket

Ubuntu Linux, 2.6.32-45 kernel, 64b, Perl 5.10.1

I connect many new IO::Socket::UNIX stream sockets to a server, and mostly they work fine.  But sometimes in a heavily threaded environment on a faster processor, they return "Resource temporarily unavailable" (EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK).  I use a timeout on the Connect, so this causes the sockets to be put into non-blocking mode during the connect.  But my timeout period isn't occurring - it doesn't wait any noticeable time, it returns quickly.

I see that inside IO::Socket, it tries the connect, and if it fails with EINPROGRESS or EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, it does a select to wait for the write bit to be set.  This seems normal so far.  In my case the select quickly succeeds, implying that the write bit is set, and the code then tries a re-connect.  (I guess this is an attempt to get any error via error slippage?)  Anyway, the re-connect fails again with the EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

In my code this is easy to fix with a re-try loop.  But I don't understand why, when the socket becomes writeable, that the socket is not re-connectable.  I thought the select guard was always sufficient for a non-blocking connect.  Apparently not; so my questions are:

- What conditions cause the connect to fail when the select works (the write bit gets set)?
- Is there a better way than spinning and retrying, to wait for the connect to succeed?  The spinning is wasting cycles.  Instead I'd like it to block on something like a select/poll, but I still need a timeout.

Thanx,

-- Steve

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand why, when the socket becomes writeable, that the socket is not re-connectable.

I imagine it's because whatever needed resource became free got snatched up before you were able to connect again. Replacing the `select` with a spin loop would not help that.

Comment: Duh! Thanx, you made the lightbulb go on in my head.  I (wrongly) thought that the first connect had caused whatever resources to get allocated and stay allocated for the socket.  I see now I was wrong on this - the EAGAIN (E-anything) status means the first connect was completely done, and failed; the second connect is a brand-new one totally distinct from the first.  Thanx!